# Ambiguous overload of pointer and integer?

Tags: c++, pointers, null, integer, overloading

The following overloaded function,

```cpp
void foo(const void*)
{
  printf("first");
}

void foo(unsigned int)
{
  printf("second");
}
```

generates an *ambiguous overload* in this case

```cpp
foo((int)0);
```

but not in this one

```cpp
foo((int)1);
```

Why? Is it because people still use `NULL`? And what's the best way to get around the problem, without explicit cast?

(I'm compiling with GCC 8.3.0-C++11 on Ubuntu 18.04)

[Godbolt conformance view](https://godbolt.org/z/jvYPKT)

**EDIT**

As some of you pointed out in the comments, `(int)0` compiles without errors, actually (at least on GCC 8.3.0, with C++11 std). The problem I had was only with `foo(0)`, and I get why now.

Comment: Indeed NULL. Why do you need an overloaded function? Can't you use different functions?

Comment: Thing is, `(int)0` shouldn't cause an ambiguity. Only a literal `0` constitutes a null pointer constant. A cast expression does not. What compiler options did you build with?

Comment: Yeah, I cannot reproduce your problem https://wandbox.org/permlink/GKRgIv2CTNZ7XhR9 - For `(int)0` the second overload is called, as expected.

Comment: I can reproduce this [here](https://godbolt.org/z/5G9Y44) with gcc, not with clang.

Comment: @StoryTeller-UnslanderMonica, I'm able to reproduce the problem in MingW64 gcc.

Comment: Apperantly in C++98 mode even `const int i = 0; foo(i);` causes an error with current versions of GCC and clang. [Demo here](https://godbolt.org/z/xGGvfM).

Comment: @anastaciu - And I'll ask you the same thing I asked the OP, with *what options*? Simply using MingW64 says nothing.

Comment: @IlCapitano - It should in C++98 mode. A defect http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/cwg_defects.html#903 that wasn't retroactively applied to C++03 is at play here.

Comment: msvc fails, gcc/clang is fine if C++11 is enabled: https://godbolt.org/z/9Yr7sj

Comment: @StoryTeller-UnslanderMonica, no options, `g++ main.cpp`, default `std=c++14`. But I see your link, in any case the problem stands in my compiler.

Comment: Yes, sorry my bad, `(int)0` doesn't cause ambiguity, whereas `0` does.

Comment: Interestingly if you remove `foo(unsigned int)` from the overload resolution, the code does not compile. I am not sure why the function `foo (const void*)` is not removed from the candidate list if with two candidates the call is ambiguous but calling the only candidate `foo(const void*)` with `(int)0` is incorrect.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The literal `0` has special meaning in C and C++, as it's also a null pointer literal.  This is how `NULL` works.

If you're calling the function with a literal, instead of `foo(0)` you could do `foo(0u)`, which works because `0u` already has the type `unsigned int`, so there's no conversion needed to call the integer overload.  If you're calling `foo` with an integer variable, there shouldn't be any conflict. (demo [here](https://godbolt.org/z/j73Ebc))

As mentioned in the comments, `(int)0` shouldn't cause any conflict, and GCC 8.3 [doesn't produce any error](https://godbolt.org/z/TzooTP) with `foo((int)0)` in C++11 mode, but [does](https://godbolt.org/z/oshr9b) in C++98 mode (and so does clang).  As mentioned by @StoryTeller-UnslanderMonica in the comments, this is caused by a defect http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/cwg_defects.html#903 that wasn't retroactively applied to C++98.

Answer (score 0):

In situations like yours, you can usually help yourself with SFINAE or `requires()`. Here is an idea, but other solutions are also possible:

```
void foo(void const*)
{
  printf("first");
}

void foo(auto a)
  requires(
    std::is_integral_v<decltype(a)> &&
    !std::is_same_v<decltype(NULL), decltype(a)>
  )
{
  printf("second");
}
```

[Demo](https://wandbox.org/permlink/mI1Vthppa2RMcZQB)

But, `NULL` does not usually present a problem in c++.